# Expansion in hypergraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvalues, expander-graphs

Is there a useful concept of expansion in hypergraphs, generalizing the concept for graphs (see: expander graphs)?

Of course, expander graphs can be characterized in several qualitatively equivalent ways (in terms of set boundaries, in terms of eigenvalues, in terms of random walks,...) so I'd expect some or all of those ways to come into play in the case of hypergraphs as well. Do they? What has been done?

**Update**. A possible suggestion: call a $d$-regular, $k$-uniform hypergraph an *$\epsilon$-expander hypergraph* if, for any functions $f_1,\dotsc,f_k:V\to \mathbb{C}$ on the set $V$ of vertices, orthogonal
to constant functions on $V$,
$$\left|\sum_{\mathbf{e}\in E} \prod_{v\in \mathbf{e}} f_i(v)\right| \leq (1-\epsilon) \frac{d}{k} |V| \prod_{i=1}^k |f_i|_2$$
for $|\cdot|_2$ the $\ell_2$ norm on $V$ with respect to the uniform probability measure. Does that make sense? Can one give an equivalent spectral definition, for some definition of "spectrum"?

Comment: I thought of adding the tag "open-ended", but it doesn't exist :(.

Comment: Some possibly relevant references I've found after a brief search: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/math-2020-0143/html https://people.math.sc.edu/cooper/ASRCH.pdf http://www.math.tsukuba.ac.jp/~wkbysh/note3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of work for simplicial complexes.  One starting point was the work of Lubotzky--Samuels--Vishne on Ramanujan Complexes (with further work by First) and later Gromov introduced a different notion of high-dimensional expansion based on geometric overlap.  A good starting point is Ori Parzanchevsky's thesis [1]

[1] [https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~zdvir/expanders/ori-thesis.pdf](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ezdvir/expanders/ori-thesis.pdf)

Comment: Thanks - I think I had glanced at the thesis briefly. How does the definition there relate to the attempt at a definition above?

Comment: (It would seem to me that it doesn't, but I may not be seeing something.)